# How to check whether element is already clicked or not in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor

I need to check whether element is already clicked/selected or not in protractor.

My scenario is given below.:
I need to check whether  the date which i am going to select is already selected in angular js calendar. However single click clear the selected date in calendar .i didnt get any method which return element is clicked or not.
E.g i need to select 11th jan in calendar so before that i need to check whether 11th jan is already selected or not
I also tried element(locator).isSelected() which returns the false value.

Kindly suggest solution which will solve my issue.

Comment: Post the link to a website when we can see this calendar in action or the relevant part of the calendar HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that once clicked, the calendar changes somehow. I'm assuming possibly that some css changed to show what was selected. I am going to make some assumptions on what this looks like. This is difficult without html. You could use [`getCssValue`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue):

Assumption that you have all your calendar dates with a css called "dates" and that the 10th item in this array of elements is the January 11th. Next assumption, the website css changes when selected. Let's say this css is called "date-selected"...

```
element.all(by.css('.date')).get(10).getCssValue().then(css => {
  console.log(css);
  // TODO: parse css and/or expect "date-selected" in "css" to be true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.